# Did Rabbenu Nissim also write the long "Ashamnu" in the Chazarah of Shacharit in the Sephardic Yom Kippur Machzor?

Tags: tefilla, sources-mekorot, yom-kippur, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, viduy-confession

Who wrote the long vidui in the Chazarah of Shacharit in Sephardic Yom Kippur Machzorim, i.e. the one that starts "Ashamnu, Achalnu ma'achalot assurot" and has a whole paragraph for each letter of the aleph-bet?

Is this part of the "Vidui HaGadol of Rabbenu Nissim", or does that name refer to just the paragraphs leading up to "Ashamnu, Achalnu ma'achalot assurot..."?